# Cannot insert data into database after retrieval

Tags: go

Need help extracting data from database ms sql and add them to the database postgres. The data extraction is successful. But with the insert problem. I can't break the interface down into 18.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

const (
// config to connect to ms sql server

// config to connect to PostgreSQL

)

func main() {
    connStringmssql := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%d;database=%s;", server, user, password, port, database)
    db, err := connect("mssql", connStringmssql)
    checkError("Error mssql connect function ", err)
    defer db.Close()
    defer fmt.Printf("Disconnected mssql!\n")

    connStringpg := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=%s", serverpg, portpg, userpg, passwordpg, databasepg, "disable")
    dbpg, err := connect("postgres", connStringpg)
    checkError("Error connect function pg ", err)
    defer dbpg.Close()
    defer fmt.Printf("Disconnected pg!\n")

    // Read sql query from file and convert it
    mssqlSelectQueryUnConvert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./sql/mssqlSelect.sql")
    checkError("Error read sql file", err)
    mssqlSelectQuery := string(mssqlSelectQueryUnConvert)

    rows, err := db.Query(mssqlSelectQuery)
    checkError("Error in sql query ", err)
    defer rows.Close()
    columnNames, err := rows.Columns()
    checkError("Error sql columns names ", err)

    objects := make([]interface{}, len(columnNames))
    objectsScan := make([]interface{}, len(columnNames))
    rest := make([]interface{}, len(columnNames))
    for i := range objects {
        objectsScan[i] = &objects[i]
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(objectsScan...)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to scan row", err)
            return
        }
        rest = append(rest, objects...)
    }
    fmt.Println(rest)

    dbInsert, err := dbpg.Exec("INSERT INTO object_test (column1...column18) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18)", rest...)
    checkError("Error dbpg insert ", err)
    fmt.Println(dbInsert.RowsAffected())
}
```

I get error:
Error dbpg insert pq: got 54 parameters but the statement requests 18

Where did I go wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Down-votes without explanation? As for a new member, this isn't useful and wouldn't help improve his question.

Comment: One of the major issues is your append.  You're creating `rest` with _length_ equal to the length of columnNames (I'm assuming from context that this is 18).  You are appending _after_ those initial 18 (empty) entries the values stored in the objects slice, on each row scan.  So the length of `rest` will be len(columnNames) * (numRows + 1), with the first columnNames entries being empty values.  If you want to create an array with a _capacity_ but 0 length, you need to do `rest = make([]interface, 0, len(columnNames))`.  This avoids append allocating, but lets you append starting at index 0.

Answer (score 2):

You're joining all of your rows into a single `rest` variable, then trying to insert them all into a single row in Postgres. This obviously won't work.

You probably need to move your `db.Insert` statement into your `rows.Next()` loop, and do one insert per row.

Comment: Is there another way to do this? I want to post these operations by function, i.e. separately make the select function and insert function

Comment: I'm sure there are countless ways to do this. But I don't understand your requirement, so I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: The output I want to have two functions. One select function that returns an interface with data. The second insert function that accepts this interface.

Comment: interfaces don't have data. So I'm not really sure what you mean. But you also seem to be focusing on your specific solution, rather than the problem, which makes this seem like a bit of an XY Problem.

Comment: OK. If you take the problem. The select function returns a structure with data? How do I write an insert function to accept this structure as input?

Comment: That's exactly what my answer tells you to do.